# How do I define a required component on a Unity game object?

Tags: unity, component-based, unityscript

I have a script that expected the game object to have a `Terrain` component.

Is there an attribute I can add (or some other way) which will prevent a designer from adding my script/component/MonoBehavior to a GameObject that does not have the `Terrain` component?

The only alternative I have been able to find is to attach my script to something else, and then have a public Terrain field, which requires the user to attach the terrain object to it.  (since the editor won't allow you to associate a different object type.) - I just want the reverse.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I changed the wording of your question a bit, since objects are not inherently terrain (or anything else), it's the components that make an object.

Comment: @Byte56 thank you, they way you changed the question solved my issue.  While I had realized that most things were based off of the simple GameObject, it had not occurred to me that Terrain was just a component attached to it.  Which would mean my original request was impossible.  :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Applying the [`RequireComponent`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html) decoration to a script will ensure that the GameObject has the specified component.

If the component is missing:

1. Unity will attempt to add a component of this type for you,
2. If this fails (e.g. mixing RigidBody/RigidBody2D) then the script will refuse to attach.

C# sample:

```
[RequireComponent (typeof (Rigidbody))]
public class PlayerScript : MonoBehaviour {
    // stuff
}
```

UnityScript sample:

```
@script RequireComponent(Rigidbody)

// stuff
```

Answer (score 3):

Unity has built in functionality for this called [`RequireComponent`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RequireComponent.html). Used like this in Unityscript:

```
@script RequireComponent(Terrain)
```

This will actually automatically add a `Terrain` component to the object if it doesn't have one already. If the user removes the `Terrain` component, your script will throw a compile error about the missing component.

Answer (score 1):

Two methods come to mind, but none are very elegant.

1) Implement `OnValidate()`. The downside is that's it's called only when modifying component's values, or entering/exiting game mode.

```
void OnValidate() {
    if (GetComponent<Terrain>() == null) {
        Debug.LogError("You can't attach this component without terrain!");
        DestroyImmediate(this);
    }
}
```

2) Make the script run in the editor, and implement `OnAwake()`. But be aware that methods like `Update()` will be called in the editor.

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
class MyScript: MonoBehaviour {
    void OnAwake() {
        if (GetComponent<Terrain>() == null) {
            Debug.LogError("You can't attach this component without terrain!");
            DestroyImmediate(this);
        }
    }
}
```